# Move git repository to a subdirectory in the same path while preserving all of its history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-mv

I have a git repository with >100 commits that I initialized awhile back in the following path:

`/Users/myusername/`

However, all of my commits are actually for files in the path:

`/Users/myusername/excess/folders/not/requiring/version/control/project_root/`

I should have initialized the repository in `project_root/`, because I don't need to version control anything in the upper directories.

Is there any easy way of changing the path of my repository so that the top level of the repository is `project_root/` while also preserving my version history as it is? Are there any extra steps to get this reflected in my remote repository as well or do I just commit and push after making the change?

Comment: Where is it now? In `control/`?

Comment: @ElpieKay the repository is currently in `~` unfortunately, although all of the commits are for files and folders inside `project_root/`. I just made some edits which hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something goes wrong, you can delete the copied `.git*` files and start over. Here is what you can do:

```
$ cp -r .git* path/to/project_root/
$ cd path/to/project_root/
$ git add -A .
```

When you call `git status`, all you should see are renames and removes now. If all looks good, you can delete `.git*` in the previous root.

Also beware that any files existed in history will remain there, that requires another operation to clean up if you have credential files etc.

Comment: One issue is that within `excess/folders/not/requiring/version/control/` there is a whole lot of stuff that I need to keep so I can't delete that. I am updating my question to reflect this and other contraints.

Comment: Yes, and I missed another point in your question. I will update it shortly.